# How to get value from response Array to Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

How to get value from response array to ajax?
let's se my response array

```
Array ( [files] => Array ( [0] => files/media_post/Hydrangeas.jpg ) [metas] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [date] => Mon, 31 Oct 2016 06:16:13 +0100 [extension] => jpg [file] => files/media_post/Hydrangeas.jpg [name] => Hydrangeas.jpg [old_name] => Hydrangeas [replaced] => [size] => 595284 [size2] => 581.33 KB [type] => Array ( [0] => image [1] => jpeg ) ) ) )
```

and my javascript

```
 data: null,
        type: 'POST',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        nama : $("#filer_input2").val(),
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>blog-media/ajax_add",
        beforeSend: function(){},
        success: function(data, el){
            alert(data.metas);
            var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();
            el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-success\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-check-circle\"></i> Success</div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");
            });
        },
        error: function(el){
            var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();
            el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-error\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-minus-circle\"></i> Error</div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");
            });
        }
```

so i hope i can get value from array because i neet that values for save to database.

Comment: Send it with `json_encode` and get it as json response.

Comment: Debug and inspect data. What do you get back?

Comment: from debug inspect i get arrray this array above.. the code nothing error but i just want get the value in array metas for save to database

Comment: does the `alert(data.metas)` not prompting you your desired value?

Comment: i have do that but stil not working 'undefined'